# What makes Pronterface wait for user?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, robo-r1+

I'm using Cura with the Pronterface UI to slice/print and sometimes printing just stops - always in the first layer - when it happens the printing screen shows "Waiting for user", when I press the button on the printer printing resumes.

I don't know when this happens, it just happens about once every 5-10 prints, when this happens if I close the printing window and immediately click "print to usb" to reopen it the problem doesn't repeat.

This only happens with the Pronterface UI, it doesn't happen with Cura basic UI or when printing using an SD card.

Not using Pronterface isn't a good option because when I'm fine-tuning a model it much more convenient to send a test print from the computer and not copy the gcode to an SD card and print from the printer.

My printer is Robo3D R1+

Comment: Hi! Do you know if this happens when Pronterface is the "program in front"? I have had issues like this where Pronterface gets starved for resources because it is laying in the background while I do other stuff on my computer.

Comment: @TormodHaugene no, its not related, it also happens when Pronterface is the active window and the computer isn't doing anything else

Answer (score 1):

That's the temperature problem that you've encountered.

The temperature of bed and hotend is reported every few seconds. Per default, first that sets is the bed temperature, then you need to wait for the bed to reach it, then warm up the hotend, and then start printing.

Comment: I don't think the problems are related, first because the stopping started long before I started messing with the warmup sequence and second because the stopping also happen after 10 minutes pre-warming

Comment: hm... can you give some more data here? My buddy had similar problem, and it was the temperature problem, so I've posted that as an answer.

Comment: I don't have more data to give, I haven't found any consistency in when this happens (except that it's always in the first layer), it just happens randomly, I really have no idea what is causing this - I will look at the temperature reading next time this happens